# Jest - Test catch block in an asyncThunk (Redux toolkit)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-redux

I've been struggling recently because I'm trying to fix some tests that another developer made before he left the company I'm working on. It involves testing a catch block inside a createAsyncThunk, the thunk was created as follows:

```js
export const onEmailSubmit = createAsyncThunk(
  'email/onEmailSubmit',
  async (data, { dispatch, rejectWithValue, getState }) => {
    dispatch(updateEmail({ isLoadingEmailRequest: true }))
    try {
      const response = await updateIdentity(data)
      return response.data
    } catch (err) {

      // If the error doesn't have any status code, there is a Network Error
      // so let's show the error modal:
      if (err.request) {
        dispatch(updateErrorModal({ showErrorModal: true }))
      }

      return rejectWithValue(err.data)
    }
  })
```

The test file is something along the lines:

```js
import userReducer, { updateEmail, handleEmailVerify } from './EmailSlice'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store' // ES6 modules
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { updateIdentity } from '../../../http'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

jest.mock('../../../http/', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('../../../http/'),
  updateIdentity: jest.fn().mockImplementation((data) => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      simpleFieldsValues: {
        displayName: 'test',
        language: 'en_US'
      }
    })
  })
}))

describe('EmailSlice unit tests', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
      value: {
        getItem: jest.fn(() => null),
        setItem: jest.fn(() => null),
        removeItem: jest.fn(() => null)
      },
      writable: true
    })
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  })

// ...Some tests before this one

it('tests when handleEmailVerify is called and backend does not return a response', async () => {
    const error = new Error()
    error.request = {
      message: 'test'
    }
    sendVerificationCode.mockImplementation(_ => Promise.reject(error))
    const store = mockStore({})

    await store.dispatch(handleEmailVerify())

    const actions = store.getActions()

    const rejectedActionLoading = actions[1]
    expect(rejectedActionLoading.type).toEqual(updateEmail.type)
    expect(rejectedActionLoading.payload).toEqual({ isLoadingEmailRequest: true })
    const rejectedAction = actions[2]
    expect(rejectedAction.type).toEqual("errorModal/updateErrorModal")
  })
})
```

The thing is that the tests fail because the dispatch to update the error modal is never reached. I think this is related to the fact that the mocked promise sendVerificationCode.mockImplementation(_ => Promise.reject(error)) does not return the object with the request object inside of it to the catch block, thus not dispatching the updateErrorModal.

PS: If I remove the if statement and just dispatch the updateErrorModal, the test passes.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks for your time :)